# Coverting hex string to int results in incorrect value. (c++ stoi, stoul)

Tags: c++, string, integer, hex

I have to convert a hex value in the string to unsigned long int and store it in a variable but when i try this, i just get "0". I think it stops converting when it reaches a char that is "x".
issue is observed with stoi, stoul

is there any function that i can use it for?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{    
   string str = "0x12234";
   unsigned long int var = std::stoul(str);
   std::cout << " var = " << var << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Output of the program
var = 0
I want the output to be
var = 0x12234

Comment: `std::hex` does conversion from and to streams.

Comment: Default `base` for [`std::stoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) is `10`. If you want it to detect the base automatically, you need to pass `0` yourself: `std::stoul(str, 0);`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen There is another parameter before the `base` parameter, so that statement needs to be `std::stoul(str, nullptr, 0)` or `std::stoul(str, nullptr, 16)` instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau Right, I missed that

Answer (score 0):

`std::stoul()` (and `std::stoi()`) has an optional `base` parameter that defaults to 10, which means it will only parse decimal (base10) digits `0-9`.  So yes, it will stop parsing on the `x`.

To parse a hex value, set the `base` parameter to 16 instead:

```
unsigned long int var = std::stoul(str, nullptr, 16);
```

Or, since the string has a `0x` hex prefix, you can set the `base` parameter to 0 to auto-detect the base as 16:

```
unsigned long int var = std::stoul(str, nullptr, 0);
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/ehfXwq)

Comment: Thanks. that does seem to work. When i print the value with cout<<hex , I get value as  [var = 12234] and without  cout<<hex  I get [var = 74292] which is expected

But this im not able to see the value to be [var = 0x12234] .  from the above method 0x is getting lost during the conversion.

Comment: @THESIGSEGV If you want `cout << hex` to output the `0x` prefix, use `cout << showbase` to enable that behavior.  I have added a demo to my answer to demonstrate this.

Comment: Thanks for the great demo. Printing the value as hex fine but what i wanted the variable to actually contain the value in hex formal itself. I' not sure if that is possible . 

unsinged long var = 0x11234

Comment: @THESIGSEGV then you clearly don't understand how numeric variables actually work. Hex is just a *representation*. Decimal is just a *representation*. An integer variable holds binary bits for a numeric value. Hex 0x12234, octal 0221064, decimal 74292, these are just different *representations* of the same numeric value.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my confusion. it makes sense now.